# Passing char array to a function to copy array to different array and output: "implicit decleration of function", what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c

The compilation errors i'm getting:

```
practice.c:8: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘a’
practice.c:13: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘a’
practice.c: In function ‘main’:
practice.c:43: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘convert’
```

I'm trying to pass an array of strings from user input to a function that copies that array into another uninitialized array, and outputs that array, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. When passing an array to a function, what does 'char**' symbolize as opposed to 'char*'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char convert(char* (*)a[][20], char* (*)b[][20]);
void get_input( char c[]);

char convert(char* (*)a[][20], char* (*)b[][20])
{
    strcpy(b[][20], a[][20]); 
    return b[][20]; 
} 

int main()
{
    char array[10][20]; 
    char array2[10][20]; 
    int i; 

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    { 
        printf(" Please input a string value \n"); 
        fgets( array[i], 20, stdin); 
    }

    convert(&array, &array2);   
    printf(" Final array \n"); 

    get_input(array2[10]);  
    return 0; 
}

void get_input( char c[])
{
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i<9; i++)
    { 
        printf("%c \n", c[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you have a declaration line for the convert function (the first line after the includes). This isn't necessary since the convert function is located before its first usage. Putting the same information in two places invites error and multiplies effort if it has to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters are wrong:

```
char * (*) a[][20] ;
```

Is not a valid declaration in `C`, and if you mean the following:

```
char ** a[][20] ;
```

This is a pointer to an array of 20 pointers to pointer to char... Which is clearly not what you want.

What you want is simply `a[][20]` or `(*a)[20]`:

```
void convert (char a[][20], char b[][20]);
```

Then your code is also wrong, don't know where you saw that... You need to loop over the array to strcpy:

```
void convert (char a[][20], char b[][20]) {
    int i ;
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i) { // Here i put 10 but you should pass it as a parameter
        strcpy(b[i], a[i]); // Simply
    }
}
```

When doing `convert(a, b)`, your `b` array is updated, no need to do `b = convert(a,b)` which won't work. And you send directly `a` and `b` to the function, no need to send the address of `&a` or `&b` which makes thing unecessary complicated.

If you'd really want to return `b`, then your function prototype would be a bit more ugly:

```
char (* convert (char a[][20], char b[][20])) [20] {
    // for loop
    return b ;
}
```

But this won't work if `b` is allocated statically like you do, you need to allocate `b` dynamically:

```
char (*b)[20] ;
b = malloc(10 * sizeof(*b)) ;
b = convert(a, b);
```

Comment: `char * (*) a[][20] ;` is a syntax error and not equal to `char ** a[][20];`

Comment: yeah, you were faster than me, so I rewrote my answer to make an addition on your answer

Answer (score 0):

here is a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert(char a[][20], char b[][20]);
void get_output(char c[][20]);

void convert(char a[][20], char b[][20])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       strcpy(b[i], a[i]); 
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char array[10][20]; 
    char array2[10][20]; 
    int i; 

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf(" Please input a string value \n"); 
        fgets(array[i], 20, stdin); 
    }

    convert(array, array2);   
    printf(" Final array \n"); 

    get_output(array2);  
    return 0;
}

void get_output( char c[][20])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", c[i]); 
    }
}
```

Holt explained some of the errors in his answer. the others are: you want to print a string and not only 1 char, so use `%s` instead of `%c` in the printf and you want to call your (renamed) `get_output` function with the whole `array2` and not with `array2[10]` which is out of bounds of the array.